# Should I encrypt serialized file?

Tags: c#, vb.net, serialization, encryption

I have an artificial intelligence project, it has trained neural networks (The neural networks are some classes and structs in my program). I'm serializing structs using `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter` class.

When a user runs the program, it deserializes classes to get answer from neural networks. (nothing new needs to be serialized)

This is an artificial intelligence project, and not open-source. So, I don't want to let anybody access my neural networks.

**Should I encrypt serialized files? And how safe is it?**

**Will it prevent others to see variable on it?**

**Will other people can use my program to encrypt my encrypted files? how to prevent doing this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should you: only you can answer that; if misappropriation represents a real risk, then sure.

Appropriate encryption will prevent anyone without the keys getting easy access to any of the contents, so indeed - the contents will be opaque. However, there are two issues:

- protecting the keys *themselves* from being taken
- the risk of a determined hacker brute-forcing the keys

Re using the program to decrypt; that depends on where you keep the keys. If the keys are in the program itself, then even if obfuscated they are vulnerable.

For a full and accurate evaluation, contact a reputable IT security consultant.

I might also note that you might want to be cautious using `BinaryFormatter`; it can be very brittle as you re-release you application.

Comment: Where should I store the keys? and What should I use instead of `BinaryFormatter`?

Comment: @Mahdi where to keep the keys is a huge question. Seriously - for all the factors in that decision you should do a lot more research than I can answer here. For "what serializer", something like XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer would be far more reliable between versions, but are obviously easy to read. But the *apparent* unreadability of BinaryFormatter should not be confused for security. You might also look at things like protobuf-net if you want version-friendly binary serialization.

Comment: @Mahdi one common option with keys would be to use rfc 2898, combined with a known salt, and prompt the user for a password. Use 2898 to urn the pw into a key; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx